# Ionic 2 proper way to use Events

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have provider for authentication in my application - `AuthHelperProvider`. When user made failed attempts to log in, log in button should be disabled. For this purpose I publish event in my provider and subscribe on the `LoginPage` component:

**AuthHelperProvider**

```
 this.http.get(query).map(res => <{error: string, clientId: string}>res.json()).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.error == '') {
        console.log(this.TAG + 'log in without errors');

        if (keepSingIn) {
          this.storage.set(this.KEEP_LOGGED_IN, true);
          this.setUsername(login);
          this.setPassword(password);
        }

        this.setClientId(response.clientId);
        this.events.publish('user:login');
        this.attemptCount = 0;
        /*this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);*/
      } else {
        console.log(this.TAG + 'log in with errors' + response.error);
        this.events.publish('user:failedAttempt',++this.attemptCount);
        this.errorHelper.showErrorAlert(response.error);
      }
    });
```

**LoginPage**

```
 this.events.subscribe('user:failedAttempt', (attemptsCount) => {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'number of failed attempts: ' + attemptsCount);
      if (attemptsCount >= 3) {
        this.isLoginBlocked = true;
        this.errorAlert.showErrorToast('Number of attempts exceeded, try to restore your account');
      } else {
        this.isLoginBlocked = false;
      }
    });
```

But I met unexpected behavior: **handler for subscribing event called `attemptsCount` times.** It looks silly, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I have just deleted my wrong answer, you should probably add your findings in an answer and accept it in a couple of days so the thread is complete with Q & A .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out the problem was in my misunderstanding of returned type for `events.subscribe()` method. So, array of arguments returned and it should look like this:

```
   this.events.subscribe('user:failedAttempt', (attemptsCount) => {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'number of failed attempts: ' + attemptsCount[0]);
      if (attemptsCount[0] >= 3) {
        this.isLoginBlocked = true;
        this.errorAlert.showErrorToast('Number of attempts exceeded, try to restore your account');
      } else {
        this.isLoginBlocked = false;
      }
    });
```